# HTML + JS - Botón data-action ¿Cómo funciona?

Tags: javascript, html, botón

Estoy haciendo ejercicios de javascript básico, acabo de comenzar.

Tengo este html(no puede ser modificado)

```
<div id="pantalla"></div>
  <div id="buttons">
    <button class="calc-button number" data-action="1">1</button>
    <button class="calc-button number" data-action="2">2</button>
    <button class="calc-button number" data-action="3">3</button>
   </div>
```

Tengo que imprimir en la pantalla, los números 1, 2 o 3 cada vez que clique en ellos.

La cuestión es que nunca había visto eso de data-action, de normal uso el id.

¿Cómo cogería el valor de esos botones con javascript?

Se que tengo que imprimirlos en la pantalla con:

```
document.getElementById("pantalla").innerHTML("");
```

Pero no se coger los numeros.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: piensa que en html puedes poner data-id, data-loquesea los atributos datas son como variables con valores que después en javascript los puedes recuperar llamando al data. y el nombre que le hayas puesto.

Answer (score 0):

si no me equivoco puedes acceder a esos valores con la función:

`document.getAttribute("data-action")`

Pero deberías acceder a ellos a través de sus clases y su posición es decir :

```
let valor = document.getElementsByClassName("number");

valor[0].innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola @Logo Profesiona Barato para poder coger los valores del data seria lo siguiente:

```
var buttons = document.getElementById("buttons").children;
for(var a = 0; a < buttons.length; a++){
   buttons[a].addEventListener('click', function(){
      document.getElementById("pantalla").innerHTML(this.dataset.action);
   });
}
```

De esta manera cuando carga la pantalla le creas un evento onclick a cada boton para poder coger el valor del data y imprimirlo.